# How to create Eloquent in nodes js like laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i will be very happy and grateful if i can get a better answer of this.
i am very much familiar with laravel, now i am also using node Js
i need someone to guide me on how to make Eloquent like laravel in Node JS.
thank you very much

Comment: Please read this before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So what exactly do you attempt to do? It seems like you have to plow through the Eloquent code first and get familiar with "active record" pattern.